# Tiles-def xml put values with html tags

Tags: html, tags, tiles

in tiles def

```
<tiles:insert definition="link">
<tiles:put name="name" value="rule<sup>tm</sup>"/>
</tiles:insert>
```

Can i use anything like this inside put value html tag.

Comment: I have the same question, have you found an answer?

Comment: I don't exactly remember in which context i asked this

Answer (score 0):

< put name="title" value="Rule & # 1 7 4 ;" / >
will render with Registered Trademark for Rule® (& # 1 7 4 ; altogether with no space)